# Converting a column of date and time of day into running seconds

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, data-cleaning

I am just wondering if there is a way that I can convert the contents of the column described in the picture I have attached to a total of running seconds where the first row is of course zero seconds so that the next row would be ~8220 seconds and so on. This would make the analysis of time-series data much easier for me.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8O8F.png)

Comment: Something like: `(df['date'] - df['date'].iloc[0]).dt.total_seconds()` Assuming your column is labeled `'date'`?

Comment: Also, in the future it's much better to provide sample data that can be easily copy and pasted, not images. Best would be to provide code that can reproduce the DataFrame with sample/random data (so that dtypes are correct). In this case something like `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='45.12Min', periods=7)})` might suffice.